# How to wait for redux to change prop - getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am waiting for the redux store to be populated so that I can reload a React Native screen but am having issues refreshing the page upon this redux state being updated.

Specifically, I am working with wix's react-native-navigation library and have started a tab based app. I push the login screen from the first screen of the tabs and don't pop it back until successful login/signup. Because of this set up, all default tab screens load before the login flow is complete and I can obtain a user authorization token. When I receive this authorization token I want to refresh one of the screens because I can now make requests with this token.

Here is currently what I have:

AuthActions.js:

```
export const facebookLogin = (id, token) => { 
//"token" here isn't the token i need -  i know, confusing
    return dispatch => {
        fetch('https://somethingsomething.com/auth/facebook/'+id+'/'+token)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson.token); // < - This is the token I need 
            return facebookSuccess(dispatch, responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return facebookFail(dispatch);
        });
    };
};


const facebookSuccess = (dispatch, data) => {
    dispatch({
        type: FACEBOOK_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: data
    });
};
```

AuthReducer.js

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FACEBOOK_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action.payload.token); //Successfully logged here
            return {
                ...state,
                ...INITIAL_STATE,
                firstName: action.payload.user.firstName,
                lastName: action.payload.user.lastName,
                user: action.payload.user.id,
                profilePicture: action.payload.user.profilePic,
                authorization: action.payload.token
                };
        default:
                ...
     }
}
```

In ComponentIWantToReRender.js:

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    console.log("Hello is anyone there?");
    console.log(nextProps);
    console.log(prevState);
    //Never called - supposed to update when new props received
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
        const { ha, foo, bar } = state.groove;
        const { user, authorization } = state.auth;
        return {
            ha,
            foo,
            bar,
            user,
            authorization, //this is the ever so special token i need
        };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { unrelatedFunctionName })(ComponentIWantToReRender);
```

In ComponentIWantToReRender.js if I log this.props.authorization during the render process it comes up undefined. This is because it hasn't been set up yet through the login process/redux. I need to wait until it's ready but am unsure how to do that. Does anyone have any advice or insight?

Comment: the redux part and `mapStateToProps` seem totally off for me. Where do  you retrieve and update value for `state.auth.authorization`? I only see you update `user` part.

Comment: @ThoVu Shoot, I left a part out in the last line of AuthReducer. Just added back the line "authorization: action.payload.token" there. Is that what you meant by mapStateToProps seems totally off?

Comment: Are you adding the connected component to the navigation correctly? You are exporting as default so make sure to import as default also. Try logging in mapStateToProps to see if its called.

Comment: If you connect redux to RN component correctly, no further action needs to be done to trigger re-rendering. You need to check for following cases: 1. Is token successfully updated? 2. Does the component get the correct state's part (console.log in `render`)? 3. Is there any parental components interfering with rerendering (`shouldComponentUpdate` is forcefully set to be always false, for instance)

Comment: This might be trivial, but be sure you are running `react 16.3` and above. Below that, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not present.

Comment: I am facing the same problem did you fix this issue?